# Tests are running too slow for local web app. using C# Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using C# selenium WebDriver(latest version), and I have written some tests for a web application

The tests have been run perfectly when the web app. is hosted on a server, but when I were trying to run the same tests for the same web app. and is hosted on my machine locally, they are very slow, 
any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: part of the problem is in senario 1 where you run tests to server 2 machines are sharing the load, in senario 2, you only have 1 ..

Comment: Like BugFinder says, you probably need a more powerful machine.  If you manually access the hosted server on your machine, you will probably find that it is slow to respond, especially if you have other stuff happening on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guys said, the whole thing is because the local machine
I have noticed that my anti-virus was running a full scan recently, so that the tests were too slow. Things are normal now on the local machine :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue you're experiencing. I have two suggestions. As @BugFinder mentioned, odds are that you need a more powerful local machine. That will help 
a ton, however there could be two other issues that you're experiencing that cause massive slowdown.

Whenever a test runs, if it fails and you do not have a [TearDown] (or if you ONLY have a [OneTimeTeardown]) the system does not dispose of the driver or the console host that Selenium uses to run tests, so there is a chance that you have massive memory leaks that could slow down testing heavily. I created a simple batch script that ends all processes related to the tests that has these two simple commands (If you aren't using IEDriverServer replace that with ChromeDriver or whatever you use):

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe /T
taskkill.exe /F /IM conhost.exe /T
```

If you are running locally you can run the batch file yourself or you can implement this into your remotely run tests through AutoIT or a similar program. If this issue is one that persists for you, you can have 5mb of memory for EACH IEDriverServer (or whatever driver you use) and a couple mb of memory for each conhost process running. If you run 100s of tests, you can see how that can add up quickly.

I hope that this answer either directly helps or gets your mind thinking about the solution to your problem.